# Sort table using jquery.ui and store the new position to database

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table named **categories** where I store the categories for an E-Commerce. This table has the following aspect:

[image]

And this is the user interface to admin the categories.
[image]

I want to make a system to sort this table using JQuery.UI.

This is what I tried, but it returns me ***500 (Internal Server Error)***

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" span="1">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col" span="1" class="table-justified hide-mobile">Estado</th>
            <th scope="col" span="1" class="table-opts">Orden</th>
            <th scope="col" span="1"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_content">
        foreach($categories as $category)
            <tr data-index="{{$category->id}}" data-position="{{$category->position}}">
                <td class="table-text">{{$category->name}}</td>
                <td class="table-text table-justified hide-mobile">
                    if ($category->visibility)
                        <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
                    else
                        <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
                    endif
                </td>
                <td class="table-text table-opts">{{$category->position}}</td>
                <td class="table-opts">
                    <div class="operations">
                        <a href="{{url('/admin/categories/'.$category->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn-edit pV-8 pH-12" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Editar">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="{{url('/admin/categories/'.$category->id.'/delete')}}" class="btn-delete btn-confirm pV-8 pH-12" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Eliminar">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table_content').sortable({
            cancel: 'thead',
            stop: () => {
                var items = $('#table_content').sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'data-index'});
                var ids = $.grep(items, (item) => item !== "");
                $.post('{{ url('/admin/categories_list/reorder') }}', {
                    ": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
                    ids
                })
                .fail(function (response) {
                    alert('Error occured while sending reorder request');
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the controller function:

```
public function postCategoriesReorder(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'ids' => 'required|array',
        'ids.*' => 'integer',
    ]);

    foreach ($request->ids as $index => $id){
        DB::table('categories')->where('id', $id)->update(['position' => $index+1]);
    }

    return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
var tableData = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Cat 1",
  visibility: true,
  position: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Cat 2",
  visibility: false,
  position: 2
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Cat 3",
  visibility: true,
  position: 3
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Cat 4",
  visibility: true,
  position: 4
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Cat 5",
  visibility: true,
  position: 5
}];

$(function() {
  function updateTable(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, r) {
      var row = $("<tr>", {
        "data-index": r.id
      }).data("row", r).appendTo("#table_content");
      $("<td>", {
        class: "table-text"
      }).html(r.name).appendTo(row);
      $("<td>", {
        class: "table-text table-justified hide-mobile"
      }).html("<i class='fas fa-eye'></i>").appendTo(row);
      if (!r.visibility) {
        $(".fa-eye", row).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
      }
      $("<td>", {
        class: "table-text table-opts"
      }).html(r.position).appendTo(row);
      $("<td>", {
        class: "table-opts"
      }).appendTo(row);
      $("<div>", {
        class: "operations"
      }).appendTo($("td:last", row));
      $("<a>", {
        href: "/admin/categories/" + r.id + "/edit",
        class: "btn-edit pV-8 pH-12",
        title: "Editor",
        "bs-toggle": "tooltip",
        "bs-placement": "top"
      }).html("<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>").appendTo($("td:last > div", row));
      $("<a>", {
        href: "/admin/categories/" + r.id + "/delete",
        class: "btn-delete btn-confirm pV-8 pH-12",
        title: "Eliminar",
        "bs-toggle": "tooltip",
        "bs-placement": "top"
      }).html("<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>").appendTo($("td:last > div", row));
    });
  }

  function gatherData(table) {
    var rows = $("tbody > tr", table);
    var item;
    var results = [];
    rows.each(function(i, el) {
      item = $(el).data("row");
      item.position = i + 1;
      results.push(item);
    });
    return results;
  }

  updateTable(tableData);

  $('#table_content').sortable({
    cancel: 'thead',
    start: (e, ui) => {
      start = $('#table_content').sortable('toArray', {
        attribute: 'data-index'
      });
    },
    stop: () => {
      ids = gatherData("table");
      console.log(start, ids);
      /*
      $.post('/admin/categories_list/reorder', {
          "csrf-token": $("meta[name = 'csrf-token']").attr("content"),
          ids
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
          alert('Error occured while sending reorder request');
          location.reload();
        });
        */
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" span="1">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col" span="1" class="table-justified hide-mobile">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col" span="1" class="table-opts">Orden</th>
      <th scope="col" span="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_content">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This should allow you to pass the new position for each ID to the script so the Database is updated.

Comment: I tried this, but on `updateTable(tableData);` I put `updateTable($categories);` witch is the data I get from Controller and it returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: $categories is not defined`

Comment: @martibellot that may be a PHP Variable and is not read by JavaScript. Either way the error reports that the variable does not exist or is not defined.

Comment: @martibellot also `updateTable()` was largely to just build the table data for the example. You should not need to use it.

Comment: Okey, I have used my code to set the table content, but with my code, I can't use your function gatherData()..., I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'position')`.